# Products of general distributions

Tags: python, statistics, scipy, statsmodels, pymc

Say I have two unnormalized, non-parametric distributions for a random variable between [0,1], e.g.:

```
unnormalized_pdf_A = abs(sin(linspace(1,10,100)))
```

and

```
unnormalized_pdf_B = abs(cos(linspace(1,10,100)))
```

I would like to obtain the pdf of the variable `C = A*B` as well as get some basic statistcs of it (e.g. mean, variance and/or bayesian intervals)

Is this doable with `statsmodels`, `PyMC` or `scipy.stats`? How can I start approaching this problem?

Comment: This should be what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889025/product-of-two-beta-distributions/21892843#21892843

Comment: Thanks @jseabold. If I am not mistaken, your post assumes that you can sample directly from the (parametric) distribution (the call `y = stats.beta(.5, .9).rvs(N)` does the sampling). In my case, all I have is unnormalized functions defined between 0 to 1. I understand that once I have the samples, I can multiply them (goal of the question) and fit `sm.nonparametric.KDEUnivariate(samples)` to get the PDF. The problem is therefore getting samples from the functions in the OP. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: There's actually a closed form solution for the draws from the beta, so I didn't need to sample there. I just happened to draw from the beta distribution in that example to illustrate a general way to do what you want (I think), but you could just sub in your random values also confined to (0, 1). The KDE estimator in the steps after the draw doesn't know that's a draw from a beta distribution. If you lower the sample size, the PDF won't look anything like the parameterized beta.