# How to multiply 2 Beta functions in julia0.6.2?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

I have two random variables:

B1 ~ Beta(α1,β1)

B2 ~ Beta(α2,β2)

I would like to compute distribution of Z = B1*B2 (the product of the random variables)

Using `Julia`, how can I get the pdf of a single Beta with:

```
x = collect(0:0.001:1);
b1 = Beta(11,41);
b2 = Beta(41,11);
posterior = pdf.(b1.*b2,x);
```

I get this error `MethodError: no method matching *(::Distributions.Beta{Float64}, ::Distributions.Beta{Float64})`

Comment: Could you use a MixtureModel function from the Distributions package?

Comment: I don't know if this counts as a duplicate, but the [exact same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21889025/1346276) has been asked for Python. Are you looking for a translation of the simulation code in the answers there, or for an implementation of an analytical solution? (The reason why `Distributions` does not provide that operator is because it's difficult in general.)

Comment: @phg I am looking for implementation of an analytical solution.

Comment: I do not think there is s package providing an analytical solution to your problem. The product of two independent Beta random variables does not have a well-known distribution. There are some math.stackexchanhe questions and papers about this topic.